# AndroidStudio - Module Dependencies in Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, slidingmenu

I have a little problem compiling an android application using module dependencies in Android Studio.

So, I want my application to use the library 'slidingmenu' (link [here](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)).

Here is my application tree:

- Application
- slidingmenu (source files)
- slidingmenu-maps-support (source files)

Here is a [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BZbQ.jpg) to see what I mean.

This is the error I'm getting.

> Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':Application'.
>
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
>
> Configuration with name 'default' not found.

How do I specify a module dependency and where do I put the modules (inside Application or inside ApplicationProject?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
*Never mind! I got back to eclipse! Android Studio is just not ready for a true project development.*

Comment: lol don't just give up!

Comment: This happens when I want to learn something. If I can in one way, I try something else. I moved to IntelliJ on which AndroidStudio is based and basically is the same thing. In one way or another.
First of all, learn your IDE. This is what I learned. :)

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You should put your library modules inside the Application Project. In order to specify a module dependency, simply:

1. Right click on *Application*->*Open Module Settings*
2. Click on the '+' icon
3. Select the root directory for your library module you'd like to add.
4. Follow the prompts

Then, this module will show up in your project. Then, you need to add it to *Application* as a library dependency. Once again, in your *Module Settings*:

1. Select your *Application* module
2. Select the *Dependencies* tab on the right
3. Click the '+' icon on the bottom
4. Select *Module Dependency*
5. Select your desired library module

Comment: Thanks Karim. Kinda late but better later than never right?

Comment: Hi @KarimVarela I am getting this error after including the module as dependency. `Error:Execution failed for task ':library:processReleaseGoogleServices'.
> No matching client found for package name 'com.firebase.ui'`

Comment: The desccription is outdated and step 3. above is not possible at all

Comment: You may have to expand the window to find the `+` icon. It was at the bottom for me, and hidden until I expanded the window. AndroidStudio loves to present windows that are too small and aren't obvious that they need to be expanded...

Comment: I wonder why adding module like this does not update gradle file?

Answer (score 71):

For people using the gradle way (explicitly rather than being generated by the IDE):

Add this to your app's `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ....
    // other dependencies...
    implementation project(':module-name')
}
```

Comment: I couldn't for the life of me add a dependency through the project dependencies. I could click the +, add module dependency and then when I came back to the module settings window it wouldn't be there. Doing this in my gradle file under dependencies worked!

Comment: this is deprecated now

Comment: I doubt it is deprecated Kathi

Answer (score 2):

**Add module as dependency**

1. Add module into `settings.gradle`

```
include ':MyModule'

//Additionally you can specify  directory here
project(':MyModule').projectDir = new File('SomePath/HelloWorld')
```

2. Add dependency into module

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':MyModule')
}
```

3. Sync Project