# Getting this error while login: at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)

Tags: java, android

This is not duplicate question I found error from server side as POST method is sending any response because I have checked with all post API non of them are working but with GET method they are working fine.
I simply got stuck with this error. Need a fresh eye to figure it out as I'm not able to find. I'm trying to login but I don't know what happened to my code, since before 15-20 days ago it was working fine, and now not getting any response from android side but from server side I'm getting response. Help me to find out what mistake I'm doing.This question is not duplicate i'm getting response from server side but not from android side. Even my code was working fine as i defined now it's not working . As i'm not able to find out solution that's why I need some one help. so please help me simply don't mark it as duplicate. Thanks in Advance.

Here is my MainActivity Code :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 EditText usernameEditText,passwordEditText;
 Button loginButton;

    /*public static final String ROOT_URL = "";*/

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         usernameEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);

         passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);

         loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginButton);

        loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                final String email = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
                    if (!isValidEmail(email)) {
                        usernameEditText.setError("Invalid Email");
                    }

                    final String pass = passwordEditText.getText().toString();
                    if (!isValidPassword(pass)) {
                        passwordEditText.setError("Invalid Password");

                    }else{

                    final String username = usernameEditText.getText().toString();
                    final String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

                    Response.Listener<String>  responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                String success = jsonResponse.getString("LoginResult");

                                if ( success.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){

                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "button Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent( MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }else {

                                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                    builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                            .setNegativeButton("Retry",null)
                                            .create()
                                            .show();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };



                    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest(username, password, responseListener);
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                    queue.add(loginRequest);

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    // validating email id
    private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
        return matcher.matches();
    }

    // validating password with retype password
    private boolean isValidPassword(String pass) {
        if (pass != null && pass.length() > 6) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my LoginRequest Code :-

```
public class LoginRequest extends StringRequest {

    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginRequest(String username, String password, Response.Listener<String> listener) {

        super(Method.POST, "http://example.com/tracker/loginApi/RestController.php?view=login&username="+username+"&password="+password, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password",password);

    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {

        return params;
    }
}
```

Here is my Logcat :-

```
05-23 13:02:02.613 13012-13012/com.example.bsmc.moneytracker I/ActivityThread: Finishing stop of ActivityRecord{16787f9 token=android.os.BinderProxy@512dec0 {com.example.bsmc.moneytracker/com.example.bsmc.moneytracker.MoneyTracker.Activity.MainActivity}}: show=false win=com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow@3671f29
05-23 13:02:25.744 13012-13024/com.example.bsmc.moneytracker I/ActivityThreadEui: scheduleResumeActivity com.example.bsmc.moneytracker.MoneyTracker.Activity.MainActivity
05-23 13:02:26.992 13012-13012/com.example.bsmc.moneytracker W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
05-23 13:02:27.024 13012-13012/com.example.bsmc.moneytracker W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:449)
        at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
        at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
        at com.example.bsmc.moneytracker.MoneyTracker.Activity.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:72)
        at com.example.bsmc.moneytracker.MoneyTracker.Activity.MainActivity$1$1.onResponse(MainActivity.java:67)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:78)
        at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
        at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5568)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here Is Error Logcat :-

```
05-23 15:47:54.691 1404-2692/? E/qti_sensors_hal: waitForResponse: pthread_cond_timedwait() rc=110 (cond: 0)
    deactivateSmd: ERROR: No response from the request
05-23 15:48:09.126 32426-32485/? E/SQLiteLog: (9) statement aborts at 12: [SELECT response_data, write_ms, invalid_flag FROM cache_table WHERE request_data=?] 
05-23 15:49:04.664 3683-3683/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Empty response
    [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: NO_SUCH_ELEMENT
05-23 15:49:04.742 3683-3683/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Empty response
    [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: NO_SUCH_ELEMENT
05-23 15:49:04.821 3683-3683/? E/PhoneInterfaceManager: [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Empty response
    [PhoneIntfMgr] iccOpenLogicalChannel: Exception: com.android.internal.telephony.CommandException: NO_SUCH_ELEMENT
05-23 15:49:35.676 4927-4941/? E/SDK: [SourceFile:-1] - SimpleHttpHelper RESPONSE failure:
    code=204
    result=
    url=http://ad.adapter.kaffnet.com/adserver/v1/promote/ads/sdk/repair
05-23 15:49:35.678 4927-4942/? E/SDK: [SourceFile:-1] - SimpleHttpHelper RESPONSE failure:
    code=204
    result=
    url=http://ad.adapter.kaffnet.com/adserver/v1/promote/ads/sdk/v5
```

Comment: show your json please.

Comment: Thanks@IntelliJAmiya
here is my json :-  {"Login Result":"true"}

Comment: kindly Check answer.

Comment: I'm using this in my code by mistake space deleted between Login Result. Here :-  JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                                String success = jsonResponse.getString("Login Result");

Comment: Thanks @ReazMurshed I have already checked that but not able to find solution that's why posted here please help

Comment: According to IntelliJAmiya's answer, the response code is not 200 anymore. I think during past 15-20 days that you were absent from this code, some changes happened in server code and they are not responding as they did. .server response may be empty or bad formatted now. This could be because of some logic change that you must follow and change yours too or simply their  mistake at some point

Comment: Thanks @MarziehHeidari for reply. I'm checking from server side and let you know. But through url i'm getting json data `{"Login Result":"true"}`