# Android studio merging two projects into 1 mobile application

Tags: java, android

I'm currently learning how to make mobile applications. I got sources from here and git and coded them on different projects, I found a way to make those things work but my main problem is how to merge those projects into 1 fully working application and use intent to call each applications out. I've tried importing those projects as modules but it seems so confusing. Thank you.

Comment: Go look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528400/how-to-combine-one-android-studio-project-into-another-android-studio-project) an other people have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can't merge different projects as one application as it is. You need to make one project as application module (with `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` in the first line of its `build.gradle`) and make the other project as library module (with `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` in the first line of its `build.gradle`).

After that, you need to remove the app `applicationId` line in the library module. Then you can try to call the Activity from the another project (which has been converted as library).

Comment: my login module is my main activity so im going to call it from a library project? which of the two would land whenever i run my application? or should i make my login module into a login library?

Comment: whenever the user hits login (login module), i called my library module using intent

Code:
Intent accountsIntent = new Intent("health.care.com.healthcare");

            accountsIntent.setPackage(this.getPackageName());
            emptyInputEditText();
            startActivity(accountsIntent);

is this correct? thank you

Comment: The activity with `      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
      </intent-filter>` will be the first entry to your application. If I'm not wrong, you can call the entry activity from any module. But it's better to make the entry activity inside the application module.

Comment: Whenever you have include the library module, you can call the activity directly via intent. Something like `Intent accountsIntent = new Intent(context, AccountActivity.class); startActivity(accountsIntent)`. Do not use String for the class name. You will easily make a bug because of it.