# Merging two android studio projects from github

Tags: android, android-studio, github, merge, termux

I'm trying to merge a project called [Termux-app](https://github.com/termux/termux-app) from github with its extensions (termux-boot, termux-api, termux-float all opensource from github) to complete it i used the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528400/how-to-combine-one-android-studio-project-into-another-android-studio-project) and it seems to work with termux-app and termux-boot but when i tried to do it with termux-app and termux-api i found some problems, I've been trying to understand what does the errors mean but i had no success.
Some posts said that probably it was because of [android studio gradle 3.0 migration](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration) but i've checked the xml files of [termux-api](https://github.com/termux/termux-api) and it seems to follow the suggestions.

So i have no idea why after adding the module to termux-app and rebuilding the project i got the errors:
[image]
[image]

The steps that i did to make termux-app and termux-boot work are this:

1. Download both projects.
2. Modify the build.gradle of termux-boot and made it a library deleting the ApplicationID, shrinkResources line and changing 'com.android.application' to 'com.android.library'.
3. Rebuild to generate the aar file in order to add it to termux-app project
4. From termux-app project click on menu 'File/New/New Module' added the file aar.
5. Added the dependecy by clicking on 'File/Project Structure/', click on 'app', click on 'dependencies' and on '+' in order to add the dependecy.
6. Android studio will show a problem with the manifest merged, open the manifest file and clicked on all the 'suggestions' of android-studio to solve the problem.

I repeated the same steps to merge termux-api and termux-app but it didnt work.

It isnt a questions related only to this termux-app but its more about 'the right way to merge two android-studio projects from github'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Found out that this method was right, It is elegant and works.
My problem was that i had to add a dependency that was in Termux-api and that Termux-api wasnt able to find its resources.

In order to solve this I copied and pasted all the resources from Termux-api to Termux-app and I added the dependency:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

that was supposed to be called from Termux-api.