# How to combine two android studio project and use it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, open-source, aar

I have source code of an application of torrent downloader(https://gitlab.com/proninyaroslav/libretorrent).
I want to add it to my application.

On stack overflow i find out that first make it library (aar) [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33528400/how-to-combine-one-android-studio-project-into-another-android-studio-project) and then use in my application But I don't understand how to call/access it from my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you imported the library package into your code?

Try adding `import org.proninyaroslav.libretorrent;` at the top of your class.