# Android Studio: Cannot find symbol class

Tags: android, symbols

i am a newbie in making android apps in using android studio. i am doing the qr code make using zxing. i follow the website to do the steps which like adding the module and dependencies. However now i got these kind of errors. Can somebody help me in fixing it? thanks a lot.

**coding part**
[image]

[message part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmA7t.jpg)

Comment: Looks like dependency against zxing is missing, in such case, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656023/androidstudio-module-dependencies-in-gradle.

Comment: i already add in the module setting there...but still the same...

Comment: I should, ah, also you should next time, look into the message part, which says 'bad class file magic(cafebabe) or version (0034.0000)'. it looks like you're using Java8.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662801/bad-class-file-magic-or-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your mouse cursor on this error and click alt+enter to import class.This error existed because import havn't been declared.

Comment: thanks i made it already but when i debug the program. Now come out another problem.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Can i know how to solve it?Thanks again.

Comment: i edited my post already. Just click the message part link then it will show. Thanks.