# How to import Package from One Directory to another Directory in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[This is My Android Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4LoP.png)

I want to import the custom package from the directory app to the directory sample .How to do it guys ???

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656023/androidstudio-module-dependencies-in-gradle

Comment: Simply click on package name & press alt+shift+v, one dialog will be open and follow the further steps and move your package wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try: **Right click on package > Refactor > Move**, then press OK and select destination.

It's a safe way to move package, all dependencies will be changed.