# Adding PullToRefresh from git in android studio

Tags: android, git, listview, android-studio, build.gradle

Im building an app using android studio and i want to add PullToRefresh feature to my list view.
I found https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh which is a written project to do PullToRefresh.
The problem is that i dont know how to add it to my project.

I tried adding the repository to my build.gradle but it didnt work.

can someone help me and tell me what should i do?

Thank You.

Comment: Press the button to sync gradle

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old library, do not use it.

Instead use [SwipeRefreshLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) from support library.

Check this 
[SwipeRefreshLayout with ListView done right](http://nlopez.io/swiperefreshlayout-with-listview-done-right/).

Answer (score 0):

There is **no Dependency** provided.

So you need to download the **zip** file from that link, then extract it and copy the "**Library**" folder and paste it in your Application folder

i.e. if your App name is "**HelloWorldDemo**" then paste "**Library**" folder in "**HelloWorldDemo**"(HelloWorldDemo/Library).

After this process open your project in android studio, "Library" module will show up in your project. Then, you need to add it to Application as a library dependency and then follow this instruction :

In your Module Settings:

1)    Select your Application module

2)    Select the Dependencies tab on the right

3)    Click the '+' icon on the bottom

4)    Select Module Dependency

5)    Select your desired library module (Library Folder)

**Check this links for ref :**

1) [AndroidStudio - Module Dependencies in Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18656023/androidstudio-module-dependencies-in-gradle)

2) [How do I add a library project to Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-android-studio)

Hope it will help :)