# Can I create submodule(module inside module) in Android Studio

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I have some modules`(facebook, twitter, vk).` I want to develop module for auth using social libs, but facebook and others develop sdk as modules. I want to compose all modules to one module which I can add to application.

**How can i compose  all modules   to one module?  Are there submodules?**

Answer (score 0):

You can have four modules inside your project

```
Module 1(Facebook)

Module 2(Twitter)

Module 3

  Depends on Module 1 and Modules 2

Main Module

  Depends on Module 3
```

in future if you want to include another module in your project you will not have to change build scripts of your main module.

**EDIT :**

Now your `Module 3` is an independent module which you can use anywhere you want to integrate all these sub-modules like `Module 1`, `Module 2`,...so on.

I have never tried but you can refer this link if you want to use same module among multiple projects or if your `Module 3` doesn't lies inside your project directories :

[Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle)

Comment: This way does not allow easily to add this library to another project. I want to unity many folders(modules) to one folder.

Comment: have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle

Comment: Check my Edit in answer .