# Shared Library On Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, android-studio

I'm switching from Elcipse to Android Studio. In Eclipse I have some "library projects" (no jar files, but Android projects marked as "library") that are used by several apps. In Eclipse I used to have this library project in only one place, and I liked to modifiy the library only once, and see the effect on all the other projects depending on it.

In Android Studio, when I add a library module, all the code is copied inside the app. I don't like it, because it's easier to maintain having it only in one place. Is there any way to reference the original library instead of copy it inside the project?

I've been reading a lot of about this, but I can't find the right solution. These are the ways I'm thinking to do it:

a) Aar files and local maven repository: I would compile the library module into an aar file, and I'll save in an local maven repository, so I can reference it on my projects. But this has a drawback: every time I want to modify the library, I need to recompile to an aar file before I can test the changes in my project.

b) Symbolic links: Instead of copy all the library module inside the app folder, I'm thinking in creating symbolic links to the original folder. So the library will stay in only one folder. But I think this approach is so tricky, and there must be a better way to do it.

Comment: Hi Sergio, did you find a way of doing this? I'm also having this issue, I would like to know your solution

Comment: No. I switched back to eclipse

Comment: Hey Sergio, I follow the this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle it worked for me