# Avoid code duplication in Android Studio modules

Tags: android, module, android-studio, android-library

I've created a project and a library separately using Android Studio, each in a separate folder inside some directory.

I tried to add the library as a module to the project, and noticed that instead of just referencing the library like in Eclipse, the library was copied inside the project directory.

That means that if this happened N times for N projects, then I'll have N copies of the library and I'll need to update them all when any update is to be done.
I'm working on v 1.0.2 of Android Studio.

Any one has a better idea to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three options I know of:

1. You can specify the path to the external library:

[Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle?rq=1)

2. Include the compiled jar file from the library in the `libs` directory of the `N` apps.
3. Publish the artifact (the jar from library project) to a gradle repository and then you can add dependencies to that project just like you would for the support library etc.

See http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_management.html

Comment: I'm trying the first solution, but seems that 'projectDir' is deprecated in the new gradle. Do you no what is the alternative?

Comment: Sorry no, I've not used it myself.

Comment: Did you look at some of the other answers on that question I linked to, some of them appear newer than the accepted answer so might be the right way to do it now.