# Android studio how to maintain shared library?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I have two apps, one free and a paid version with more features. I am placing the shared code in an external library as encouraged in android docs.

But when I import the library project, it just copies all files to the existing project then I'm left with two separate projects to maintain making a shared library seem pointless.

How can I maintain the library separately, where changes will show in both projects (both the free and paid versions)?

Comment: Have you considered using flavors instead of two separate projects?

Answer (score 0):

After searching I've found I can add a reference by setting the path to the library as described in the answer found here: [Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle)