# how can I add my library project as a gradle dependency?

Tags: android, mobile, gradle

I have a reusable library which I use for all the projects that I work on. At the moment, to link the library to the project, I create a symlync, include it in settings.graddle....etc. Is there a way to simplify this? The ideal situation would be for me to add it just in the mobile.graddle file

i.e

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.0.0
```

Any pointers and how to achieve this is highly appreciated.

Note: I'm not willing to share the lib with the world.

Comment: I think you are looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17490233/5320080).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this link can help you: https://jitpack.io/private#auth

Comment: Looks good. I also found this quite interesting http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-setup-private-maven-repository/en

Answer (score 0):

1. Android Studio-
   File -> New -> Import Module (Locate the module and choose it and click Finish.)
2. Once the module has been imported, File ->  Project Structure -> Dependencies -> click + -> Choose Module dependency.