# Android sync failed: Project could not be found

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I tried to sync an android project after I have changed the file `settings.gradle` to the following content (added the third line)

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:volley'
project(':LibraryModule').projectDir = new File('/home/alexander/Projects/AndroidStudio/LibraryProject/LibraryModule')
```

in order to use the code in `LibraryModule` in my current project. However the sync fails with the following message:

```
Error:Project with path ':LibraryModule' could not be found.
```

But the file `/home/alexander/Projects/AndroidStudio/LibraryProject/LibraryModule` does exist and contains the following two files:

```
LibraryModule/build/outputs/aar/LibraryModule-debug.aar
LibraryModule/build/outputs/aar/LibraryModule-release.aar
```

What is wrong this time...?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio add external project to build.gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle)

Comment: That other folder is just `build/outputs`? No Gradle files on its own?

Comment: There are more files in there. Shall I list everything?

Comment: But I had the impression that those aar files are the most important ones

Comment: I was under the impression that Gradle is going to compile the code in that library directory, not just copy some AAR files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
include ':app'
include ':libraries:volley'
include ':LibraryModule'
project(':LibraryModule').projectDir = new  File('/home/alexander/Projects/AndroidStudio/LibraryProject/LibraryModule')
```

Comment: That worked!! Thanks. Do you know some good tutorial on the settings.gradle file?

Comment: Not really :) Just had same problem and i remembered it