# import a java class in both Projects Android Studio

Tags: java

I have a java class called **MyFunctions.java** that I use in two *Projects (A, B)*. This make **two** files of the same. It's posible to create a folder called "SharedCode" and put the **MyFunctions.java** inside, and link this file in both projects?

Comment: How are you using it? Include? If so , you can load it from any location.

Comment: I try put **include '../SharedCode/MyFunctions.java';** in **settings.gradle** but don't work

Comment: Yes, that is possible. So what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0):

Create a project for MyFunctions.java (say util ) and it in both the project A and B.
In Eclipse add it in the path by : right click on project (A or B) -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Projects -> Add

Comment: I'm using Android Studio

Comment: @richard1994x you should be able to do that in android studio as well. Create a jar and add that in the library. These links [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library?rq=1) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I gonna show my solution:

1. **First**, I make a .JAR of my library
2. **Import the .JAR to your Project** in **libs folder** and make this *as library*
3. Add **compile files('../../YourJar.jar')** in your **dependencies** of *module build.gradle*

Now, I can acccess mys functions in one patch only for all projects.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Gradle Java module in a new Gradle project and link that module in your `settings.gradle`. After that you can declare the module as a dependency in your app/library module. Essentially what's described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29603354/304266.).