# android-merging projects of different users

Tags: android, android-studio, merge

i have two projects, one was made by me and the other is made by my friend on android studio - therefore different users - but when I merged the two projects one of them didn't have the green -online like- icon, and I was wondering if the different users were the reason for that? and if so what am I supposed to do to merge them together?

["AboutUs" is the name of my project in which i have merged, it was made on my laptop, "app" is the project of my friend, made on her laptop and she sent it to me to merge the two.
note: app is the orignal project and AboutUs was merged on on top of it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2vco.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle)