# How to add a gradle java project as dependency to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I followed all the tutorials in stackoverflow about this.

I have an android app in `project/android`, and a second project in `project/api`. What can I do in `project/android` to add `project/api` as a dependency?

I followed [Android studio add external project to build.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479076/android-studio-add-external-project-to-build-gradle) by doing

```
include ':VenkoAPI'
project(':VenkoAPI').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../api')
```

in settings.gradle

and then

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':VenkoAPI')
```

in build.gradle. I'm getting

```
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :VenkoAPI.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :VenkoAPI.
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve project :VenkoAPI.
```

What do these errors mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your settings.gradle as

```
include ':Project', ':API_PROJECT_NAME'
```

And in your build.gradle:

```
implementation project(path: ':API_PROJECT_NAME')
```

This works for me.

Comment: Are both the projects inside the same main folder?