# How to include java library in existing Android project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-library

I want to include [zxcvbn](https://github.com/nulab/zxcvbn4j) in my existing android project but unable to do it. 
Already try
[How to import existing java project into android studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197775/how-to-import-existing-java-project-into-android-studio)
[Android Studio: add project as library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16983364/android-studio-add-project-as-library)
[Adding external Android and Java projects to Android projects in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16835290/adding-external-android-and-java-projects-to-android-projects-in-android-studio)

but no luck. According to my project requirements i will not use **'compile com.nulab-inc:zxcvbn:1.2.2'** because i need source code in my project.

My build.gradle

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xx.xxx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true


    }

    dexOptions {

        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'http://guardian.github.com/maven/repo-releases' }
}
dependencies {
    compile files('libs/xx-3.0.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/xx-android-sdk-1.6.3.jar')

    compile project(':utilities')

    compile project(path: ':common')
    compile project(':common')

    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev164-1.20.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.xx.xx:xx:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.x.x:x-compiler:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.x.x:x-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.0.2'
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Comment: You need `mavenCentral()` as a repostiory in the gradle file

Comment: @cricket_007: In zxcvbn4j/build.gradle (https://github.com/nulab/zxcvbn4j/blob/master/build.gradle)  mavenCentral() is mention. In my project gradle mavenCentral() also mention.

Comment: Please show your gradle file - doesn't matter what is in that file you linked to

Comment: @cricket_007 : Now you can see my gradle file

Answer (score 2):

You should import as new module for your android project follow the below steps to add as a new module

```
 1.Go to file -> New - > Import Module
```

and select your  zxcvbn library location path and click finish. This will add a new module to your existing android project.

Then you should add a new module i,e your ( zxcvbn library ) to your project dependency to do that

```
 2.Click project structure options - > dependency select your  zxcvbn library and click ok and synch project
```

Now your java library included in your android project

Comment: I already try this but its not work. When i point zxcvbn folder than Android studio shows message "please provide module", if i point to build.gradle than its import only gradle file in incorrect format.

Comment: Then may be you pointing to the wrong folder or wrong library which is not accepted by android studio